# Is there DroneDeployApi listener on annotations changed?

Tags: dronedeploy

I am curious to know if there is an embedded listener on area annotations change/creation in the DroneDeploy API?
And if there is no such option, am I correct that the best catch would be to listen clicks on div.leaflet-marker-draggable?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a change listener for annotations. You won't be able to listen to clicks on the map because every app is inside an iframe and once you're app going to "testing" it will be loaded on a different domain and you won't be able to access anything from window.top.

Other developers have also hit this problem and have simply added a refresh button.
[image]